# footer adding alot of unwanted margin to bottom tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

devs,

I'm creating random projects to get more knowledge with tailwind Css and react etc.

I'm facing this issue with a footer that is adding so much unwanted margin to my page, this question might be a duplicate but...  I looked into all StackOverflow questions and tried them but didn't work for me, most of them are not in **tailwindcss**. so I'm asking for your help

footer component code:

```
import React from 'react'
import "../index.css";

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className='min-h-screen con'>
      <footer class="p-4 bg-[#061a29] shadow text-center md:flex md:items-center md:justify-center md:p-6 dark:bg-gray-800 flex-1">
      <div className='flex flex-col items-center'>

        <span class="text-sm    text-white sm:text-center dark:text-gray-400">© 2023 <a href="https://flowbite.com/" class="hover:underline">ManooGawra</a>. All Rights Reserved. 
        
        </span>
        
        <p className='flex items-center justify-center sm:justify-start  text-white bg-[#061a29]'>
        
  <span className=''>Made With</span>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="red" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="none" className="w-[15px] mx-[5px] ">
    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12z" />
  </svg>
  <a href="some-url" className='font-os underline'>by AndiiCodes</a>
</p>

      </div>



        
        
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

index.css

```
.con {
  width: 100% !important;
  position:absolute;
 
}
footer {
  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

** I recently added the code to index.css because I tried so many stuff but couldn't figure it out :(  **

some screenshots so you can see what I mean

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

thanks for any help. please ignore my messy code, I'm working on it:)

Comment: You have your footer component wrapped in a div with the class `min-h-screen`.  That adds `min-height: 100vh;` to your footer.

Comment: I know... without the min-h-screen, it's not staying on the bottom. I also tried h-screen, I got the same results, I played with code a bit, I used h-[60%], and its kinda working on all devices well, but I don't know if that's the best way to do it, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to use an index.css

I just small changes to your code

```
<div className="bg-gray-800">
  <footer class="mt-64 md:w-[1240px] mx-auto flex flex-col justify-between py-6 sm:flex-row">
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
      <span class="text-sm    text-white sm:text-center dark:text-gray-400">
        © 2023{" "}
        <a href="https://flowbite.com/" class="hover:underline">
          ManooGawra
        </a>
        . All Rights Reserved.
      </span>

      <p className="flex items-center justify-center sm:justify-start  text-white bg-[#061a29]">
        <span className="">Made With</span>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="red"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          strokeWidth={1.5}
          stroke="none"
          className="w-[15px] mx-[5px] "
        >
          <path
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12z"
          />
        </svg>
        <a href="some-url" className="font-os underline">
          by AndiiCodes
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: well this kinda worked, although, it's not in the right position on ipad air and nest hub devices, ```<div className='h-[50%] sm:h-[65%] con'>``` this plus the code in index.css file is working fine on all screens.

Comment: I haven't any apple devices to test.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, you want the footer to stay at the bottom,

Mistake in your code is that you are using `flex-1` in your `footer`.

Try this approach,

```
<div class="con flex min-h-screen flex-col">
  <div class="flex-1"></div>  give flex-1 here so that it uses all the possible space
  <footer class="...">  footer uses only the required space at the bottom
  </footer>
</div>
```

**Note : Now you don't need `index.css` file**

Complete code

```
<div class="con flex min-h-screen flex-col">
  <div class="flex-1"></div>
  <footer class="bg-[#061a29] p-4 text-center shadow dark:bg-gray-800 md:flex md:items-center md:justify-center md:p-6">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
      <span class="text-sm text-white dark:text-gray-400 sm:text-center">© 2023 <a href="https://flowbite.com/" class="hover:underline">ManooGawra</a>. All Rights Reserved. </span>

      <p class="flex items-center justify-center bg-[#061a29] text-white sm:justify-start">
        <span class="">Made With</span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="red" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="{1.5}" stroke="none" class="mx-[5px] w-[15px]">
          <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12z" />
        </svg>
        <a href="some-url" class="font-os underline">by AndiiCodes</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]